# What criteria does Facebook use to prevent displaying the send dialog on a mobile device?

Tags: mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

With respect to webpages and webapps using Facebook's Javascript and Server side integration...

Facebook documentation notes that the send dialog is not supported on mobile devices, but they don't indicate how they make the determination that the dialog will not be shown or how we can find out.

This makes it difficult to display some alternate functionality in the right cases. For example the iphone is out, but the ipad will display the iframe version. The Nexus 7 with Chrome won't do the popup, but it doesn't have "mobile" in the user agent.

Does anybody know the criteria? ie. Regex on the user agent, or some certain feature detection?

Right now I am using browser sniffing :-(

```
function isMobile(string) {
   return /mobile|android/i.test(string || navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Which, for instance, doesn't account for the fact that iPad Safari will display this dialog as an iFrame (but not the popup).

Thanks.